# Who invented the notation $Df$ for the derivative?

Tags: derivatives, math-history

We are often taught that $f'$ came from Newton and $\frac{df}{dx}$ came from Leibniz, but who introduced $Df$? Are there other notations for this simple idea by famous mathematicians?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Euler.27s_notation) calls it "Euler's notation".  Things are misnamed all the time in math, but maybe Euler came up with it.

Comment: Some related discussion is given for this [History of Science and Math Question](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-is-the-difference-between-calculus-of-newton-and-leibniz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Euler.27s_notation), this is Euler's notation. You can find some more discussion of notations on the linked page. One other notation of particular note is $\dot x$ to mean the derivative of a quantity $x$ with respect to time. This is a reasonably common notation in physics, though is less often seen in pure mathematical contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Newton came up with $\dot{y}(t)$ (fluxion), which is still used in physics. Lagrange with $f'$.
According to [this source](http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html) $D$ was used (as operator) by Arbogast first.