# Is it improper form to interchange Lagrange's and Leibniz's notation?

Tags: calculus, notation

For example, could I write something like the following? $$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}x^2$$

Since Lagrange's notation and Leibniz's notation end up meaning the same thing, I wondered if this is generally considered to be good form.

Comment: Yes of course you can. A precision: notation f'(x) is **not** Newton's. It has been defined many years after the death of Newton, I think by Euler (to be checked) circa 1750. Newton uses dots over the quantities he derives (with respect to time in general).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the heads up. Is there a need to change the question, by the way? (Happy belated NY's!)

Comment: It is not of fundamental importance now, but historically, there has been a big conflict between Newton and Leibniz (the man of d/dx) co-inventors of differential calculus, not that much about notations but about the underlying concepts. Btw: Happy new year to you too!

Comment: @Max Li : Please the question I had asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966777/newton-vs-leibniz-notation

Comment: @JeanMarie: $f^\prime$ is Lagrange, $\dot f$ is Newton, $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} f$ is Leibniz, $Df$ is sometimes called Euler's notation but may have been first used by Arbogast (related Qs: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514707), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504331/)).

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation), Cajori ([1923](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1967725)), Jeff Miller's ["Earliest Uses of Symbols of Calculus"](https://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html).

Comment: @user182601 Thanks for the precisions and references. History of mathematics is also the history of its notations...